# choose.dir function does not work in R v4.3.2

Tags: r

In Windows 10, I have been using the function `choose.dir()` in R v4.2.3 without any problems, i.e. whenever I run `choose.dir()` in the RStudio's console, a window to select the folder is opened.

But I have updated R to v4.3.2 and this function is no longer working, as it only appears the NA value, and the interactive window to select a folder does not appear.

```
> choose.dir()
[1] NA
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this. I would sincerely appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Try `file.choose()` or `rstudioapi::selectFile()`. If you want to use `choose.dir()` you need to supply a default (e.g.`choose.dir(getwd())`).

Comment: Thanks @LMc! I knew about the `file.choose()` function, but I want to select only the folder. I know I could do `x = file.choose()`, and then extract the dirname by doing `dirname(x)`, but I just wanted to understand why `choose.dir()` is no longer working on v4.3.2.

Comment: Whoops, sorry! Interestingly it works for me on the same R version (v4.3.2) *after* I run another GUI command like `file.choose()`.

Comment: Yes, that's true! The same thing happens to me. That's very curious... 

Comment: I have just checked with another computer with Windows 11 if the function `choose.dir()` works correctly with R v4.3.2, and it does. So, maybe the problem is related with the Windows version where R is run.